# requestAnimationFrame computing elapsed time

Tags: javascript, webgl, requestanimationframe

Below is a snippet of JS/WebGL code that controls animation timing where
`requestAnimFrame` is the usual [shim](http://www.paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/). Works dandy under FireFox and Safari.
Under Chrome, the `elapsedTime` becomes negative on frames 2 and onward.
Evidently (according to [this article](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2011/05/03/better-javascript-animations-with-requestanimationframe/)) `webkitRequestAnimationFrame` does not
pass the `currentTime` argument to the `draw` callback!?! What is the proper, cross-browser method for computing the elapsed time!? THIS IS MADNESS!

```
var animationStartTime;

function draw(currentTime) {
    requestAnimFrame(draw);

    if (currentTime === undefined) {
       currentTime = Date.now();
    }

    if (animationStartTime === undefined) {
       animationStartTime = currentTime;
    }

    var elapsedTime = (currentTime - animationStartTime)/1000;

    gl.clear(gl.COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);
    drawScene(elapsedTime);
}
```

The actual WebGL program is [here](http://ezekiel.vancouver.wsu.edu). Under FireFox and Safari you will see a single animation loop -- under Chrome you will see the animation go on forever (until I fix it).

Comment: You're using the wrong shim. Read further down on that page; there's a much more robust piece of code you should use instead.

Comment: Also, on Chrome, I do *not* see an animation going on forever.

Comment: On Chrome (ver 28.0.1500.95), `requestAnimFrame` is using the native `requestAnimationFrame` method. That's all my shim does (as it should) in this case.

Comment: Well I don't understand how the difference between two of those time values can reflect anything other than the actual difference in time.

Answer (score 2):

If I got you right - you want to measure time taken by rendering function? Then you should simply do this:

```
function draw() {
  requestAnimFrame(draw);
  var start = Date.now();

  // perform your drawing

  var elapsed = Date.now() - start;
}
```

But if you need FPS (Frames Per Second), then something like that will do:

```
var FPS = 0;
var ticks = 0;
var lastFPS = 0;

function draw() {
  requestAnimFrame(draw);

  // perform your drawing

  var now = Date.now();
  if (now - lastFPS >= 1000) {
    lastFPS = now;
    FPS = ticks;
    ticks = 0;
  }
  ticks++;
}
```